# Create File with backslash by PHP

Tags: php

I want to create a file with a name containing backslash(/), e.g. 2013/2014.txt .
However, I found that php will regard it as a directory and create directory 2013 and put the content into a file 2014.txt.
How to escape the following situation?

Comment: are you sure the slash(`/`) is a valid character for a file? Same goes for the backslash (`\\`)

Comment: It is not a valid character to use in a file name. *Period*.

Comment: why not 2013/2014.txt instead 2013-2014.txt or 2013_2014.txt? you cant not find a solution here. call Microsoft.

Answer (score 3):

The example you use is a forwardslash.

/  - forward
\  - back

Both of these are not valid in any system as file names because they are used for addresses of directories.

I suggest you use a hypen. Eg. 2013-2014.txt or underscore 2013_2014.txt